# Bamboo-artifactory plugin dosen't work at elactic agent

Tags: maven, artifactory, bamboo, bamboo-artifacts

I have a problem with bamboo-artifactory-plugin at bamboo elastic-agent. Build fail with error:

```
Could not execute task  no Plugin with key 'org.jfrog.bamboo.bamboo-artifactory-plugin:maven3Task' is installed.
```

Bamboo agents on hardware run same build successfully.
I use Bamboo version 7.2, bamboo-artifactory-plugin version 3.2.1 and JFrog Artifactory version 6.18.1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As it looks like, the plugin is not installed on your agent. This may occur due to many reasons. Please try to reinstall the plugin and check the agent's logs.

For example, one possible reason is the lack of memory in the agent. If you see errors such as:

```
INFO | jvm 1 | 2020/11/10 11:12:36 | 2020-11-10 11:12:36,120 ERROR [remoteEventRebroadcasterMessageListenerContainer-1] [ScanningPluginLoader] Unable to deploy plugin 'org.jfrog.bamboo.bamboo-artifactory-plugin' from 'Unit: /Users/yahavi/bamboo-agent-home/plugins/user-installed/plugin_8527020839401694412_bamboo-artifactory-plugin-3.1.0.jar (1604999532000)'.
INFO | jvm 1 | 2020/11/10 11:12:36 | 2020-11-10 11:12:36,121 ERROR [remoteEventRebroadcasterMessageListenerContainer-1] [ScanningPluginLoader] Because of the following exception:
INFO | jvm 1 | 2020/11/10 11:12:36 | java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
```

That means your agent has insufficient heap size. I'd recommend on the resolution in this guide: https://confluence.atlassian.com/bamkb/outofmemory-errors-in-bamboo-server-or-in-remote-agent-307038120.html

**Edit**:
For Elastic agents, you can use this guide:
https://confluence.atlassian.com/bamkb/outofmemory-errors-in-bamboo-elastic-agent-826899144.html